# AssemblyLoadContext Will Not Unload

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have created a test application that utilizes the relatively new AssemblyLoadContext object. My issue now is that despite me doing everything I could find in the documentation. It does not unload. There isn't that much room for error, as all I am doing is loading then trying to unload.

```
private void FileWatcher_OnServerPluginLoaded(object sender, string e)
{
    AssemblyLoadContext alc = new AssemblyLoadContext("meme", true);

    WeakReference testAlcWeakRef = new WeakReference(alc);

    Assembly assembly = null;

    using (var fs = File.Open(e, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        assembly = alc.Default.LoadFromStream(fs);
    }

    assembly = null;

    alc.Unload();

    GC.Collect();

    while (testAlcWeakRef.IsAlive)
    {
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "It does not unload" what exactly do you mean? Is an exception thrown, or does testAlcWeakRef.IsAlive just never return false?

Comment: @ReillyWood The latter is the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are a few issues with your code:

1. `alc` never goes out of scope, so the the garbage collector is less likely to collect it. According to Pro .NET Memory Management, in Debug mode local variables will not be collected before the end of a method. This is different from [the docs example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/unloadability) in which the `AssemblyLoadContext` goes out of scope.
2. You're loading the assembly with `AssemblyLoadContext.Default`, not `alc`. Is that intentional?

If you're looking for more documentation on `AssemblyLoadContext`, the book C# 9.0 In A Nutshell covers it in detail.

Comment: Hi Riley, thank you for your reply! It should be using alc, that is an error on my part that I must have not fixed when I was messing around with the code trying to fix the unloading. Your first point seems to be the the solution to the issue!

Comment: An additional question - to do what I'm doing with an assembly-based plugin system, where plugins can be unloaded/loaded at runtime - is AssemblyLoadContext the best choice for .NET 6? As it does not allow me to use Appdomains, it appears they are deprecated

Comment: Yes, AssemblyLoadContext is the best way. C# 9.0 In A Nutshell covers this in detail in chapter 17.